# How to load the data from marklogic using DatabaseClient? java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, marklogic

I am trying to write data in marklogic using DatabaseClient but getting issue java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. I am not able to get where I am doing Wrong

Below are the code that I am running in intellij idea.

```
import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClient;
import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory;
import com.marklogic.client.document.XMLDocumentManager;
import com.marklogic.client.io.InputStreamHandle;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class data_movement {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

   DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory
          .newClient("localhost", 8000,
                  new DatabaseClientFactory.DigestAuthContext("admin", "admin")
          );

  XMLDocumentManager XMLDocMgr = client.newXMLDocumentManager();
  String docId = "/example/xml1.xml";
  FileInputStream docStream = new FileInputStream("D:/Embargo/CodeChanges/DM/xmlDoc1.xml"); ;
  InputStreamHandle handle = new InputStreamHandle(docStream);
  XMLDocMgr.write(docId, handle);
  client.release();
}
}
```

Comment: What version of the Java Client? If it's more recent, try checkConnection(). And of course make sure ML is running and that you can access localhost:8000 via your browser.

Comment: I am using "com.marklogic:marklogic-client-api:4.0.1" Java Client version

Comment: The 4.0.1 release is nearly 4 years old and tested only against MarkLogic 9.0-1 -- see https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/releases?after=4.1.2 ; if your current server is more recent than MarkLogic 9.0-1, upgrade to the client that was tested for your version of the server; if your server is MarkLogic 9.0-1, upgrade both server and client.